# Reading and decoding bytes after modification by external process raises UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, file, ansible-vault

I'm trying to encrypt a string with ansible-vault. To do this, I open two temporary files, one to hold the value to be encrypted and one to hold the password to encrypt with.

Reproducible example:

```
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile

value = "foo"
password = "bar"

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as value_file:
    value_file.write(value.encode('utf-8'))
    value_file.flush()
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as pass_file:
        pass_file.write(password.encode('utf-8'))
        pass_file.flush()
        subprocess.run(["ansible-vault", "encrypt", value_file.name, "--vault-password-file", pass_file.name], capture_output=True)
    os.system("cat " + value_file.name)
    os.system("xxd " + value_file.name)
    print(value_file.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

This results in the following output:

```
$ python src/test.py 
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
62653133373465363632343862623335363563666364366465396361633733643238623463343539
6231376131343538346662666133653932306137323131350a383531383561356261366639336461
37306461663030383164633638346566353662356461333163356633613664313762653933313363
3837356531646330660a363033363063396563326562653339633731656666656531353831623065
3539
00000000: 2441 4e53 4942 4c45 5f56 4155 4c54 3b31  $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1
00000010: 2e31 3b41 4553 3235 360a 3632 3635 3331  .1;AES256.626531
00000020: 3333 3337 3334 3635 3336 3336 3332 3334  3337346536363234
00000030: 3338 3632 3632 3333 3335 3336 3335 3633  3862623335363563
00000040: 3636 3633 3634 3336 3634 3635 3339 3633  6663643664653963
00000050: 3631 3633 3337 3333 3634 3332 3338 3632  6163373364323862
00000060: 3334 3633 3334 3335 3339 0a36 3233 3133  3463343539.62313
00000070: 3736 3133 3133 3433 3533 3833 3436 3636  7613134353834666
00000080: 3236 3636 3133 3336 3533 3933 3233 3036  2666133653932306
00000090: 3133 3733 3233 3133 3133 3530 6133 3833  137323131350a383
000000a0: 3533 3133 3833 3536 3133 3536 3236 3133  5313835613562613
000000b0: 3636 3633 3933 3336 3436 310a 3337 3330  66639336461.3730
000000c0: 3634 3631 3636 3330 3330 3338 3331 3634  6461663030383164
000000d0: 3633 3336 3338 3334 3635 3636 3335 3336  6336383465663536
000000e0: 3632 3335 3634 3631 3333 3331 3633 3335  6235646133316335
000000f0: 3636 3333 3631 3336 3634 3331 3337 3632  6633613664313762
00000100: 3635 3339 3333 3331 3333 3633 0a33 3833  653933313363.383
00000110: 3733 3536 3533 3136 3436 3333 3036 3630  7356531646330660
00000120: 6133 3633 3033 3333 3633 3036 3333 3936  a363033363063396
00000130: 3536 3333 3236 3536 3236 3533 3333 3936  5633265626533396
00000140: 3333 3733 3136 3536 3636 3636 3536 3533  3373165666665653
00000150: 3133 3533 3833 3136 3233 3036 350a 3335  1353831623065.35
00000160: 3339 0a                                  39.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(value_file.read().decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 3: invalid start byte
```

I run `os.system("cat " + value_file.name)` to verify the file gets correctly encrypted and `os.system("xxd " + value_file.name)` to see the individual bytes I'm expecting to read back. The raised exception doesn't seem to line up with this as byte in position `3` isn't `0x9a`. I'm wondering why that would be?

I assumed it might have had something to do with the file remaining open while `ansible-vault` modifies it, but replacing the `subprocess.run(...)` call with `os.system("echo baz>" + value_file.name)` seemed to work just fine.

I also tried different encodings and the only one which didn't raise an exception was `iso-8859-1` which dumped out complete gibberish.

Seeking to the start of the file using `value_file.seek(0)` before reading also made no difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having an external utility modify a file that you have open is simply not a good idea.  `ansible-vault` is almost certainly going to create a *new* file of the same name when it writes its output; your script (on Unix-ish systems at least) will be left with a file handle to the *original*, now-deleted, file.

So normally, you wouldn't expect to be able to read anything at all from `value_file` - not even the "foo" that you wrote to it, because the current file position will be just after that.  But `ansible-vault` actually calls the `shred` utility on the file before deleting it, in the (possibly incorrect) belief that this would make it harder to recover the unencrypted data.  `shred` works by overwriting the file contents with random bytes - and the default behavior is to round up the size of the random data it's writing to a multiple of the disk block size.  So that mysterious 0x9A is just one of these random bytes, the first one that happened to not be meaningful in UTF-8.